# Extract Completions Handler Block into method using typdef

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I would like to clean up my code some and extract a completion block to its own method. It's my understanding that I have to define a `typdef` with the same signature.
In the below example, I want to move the `NSURLSessionUploadTask`'s on completion handler to its own method. I've looked at the Apple documentation and other SO questions, but I don't know if I am searching for the right thing.

```
typedef void (^PostCompletionHandler)(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error);

@interface MyDemoClass()  {
@property (copy, nonatomic) PostCompletionHandler completePostHandler;
@end

@implementation MyDemoClass

- (void) post {

    NSData *postData = //data to pos;
    NSMutableURLRequest * req = //create request;
    NSURLSession * session = // create session;
    NSURLSessionUploadTask *queryTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:req
                                                 fromData:postData
                                       completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {
                                           if (error) {
                                               NSLog(@"Error: %@",error.localizedDescription);
                                           } else {
                                             NSDictionary * response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
                                             NSLog(@"Post Response: %@",response.description);
                                           }
                                       }];

    [queryTask resume];

}

-  (void)someMethodThatTakesABlock:(PostCompletionHandler)blockName {

}

@end
```

This is what I would like to do is something like this:

```
NSURLSessionUploadTask *queryTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:req
                                         fromData:postData
                               completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {
                                  // What do I do here?
                               }];





-  (void)someMethodThatTakesABlock:(PostCompletionHandler)blockName {

    //how do I access the data, response and error parameters?

    if (error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@",error.localizedDescription);
    } else {
        NSDictionary * response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
        NSLog(@"Post Response: %@",response.description);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `someMethodThatTakesABlock:` has a single parameter, which is the block. The block is a reference to code that can be executed. It does not contain data.

If you want to separate out your completion handling to a separate method, then write a method

```
- (void)processCompletionWithData:(NSData*)data response:(NSURLResponse*)response error:(NSError*)error {
  // Process it...
}
```

Then in the completion handler

```
NSURLSessionUploadTask *queryTask = 
  [session uploadTaskWithRequest:req

                        fromData:postData
               completionHandler:^(NSData* data, NSURLResponse* response, NSError* error) {
     [self processCompletionWithData:data response:response error:error];
}];
```